# How to list all activated profiles in mvn in a multimodule project

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

mvn help:active-profiles only list the profiles activate within the project + system settings you call it in.

It does not list the profiles that have been enabled/activated from i.e. the parent pom.

Any any way to actually see the full list of activated profiles by other means than trial-and-error to look at what properties are enabled or not ?

Comment: Actually, `mvn help:effective-profiles` lists all profiles enabled for the _current_ project.

Comment: Yes, which does *not* include profiles from parent Pom.

Comment: Unfortunately `mvn help:effective-profiles` does not exists. It is called `mvn help:active-profiles`.

Comment: @khmarbaise Sorry, of course it's `active-profiles`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I double-checked this and indeed, inherited profiles aren't listed when `mvn help:active-profiles` is being called. This is with `maven-help-plugin` version 2.1.1.

There is even a bug-report about this: [MPH-79](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MPH-79).

As a workaround, you can use older version:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.0.2:active-profiles ...
```

Comment: FYI, that bug report says that it has been fixed in mvn v 2.2

Answer (score 24):

Another option is `mvn help:all-profiles`, which also list inherited profiles.

> Displays a list of available profiles under the current project.
>   **Note**: it will list all profiles for a project. If a profile comes up with a status inactive then there might be a need to set profile activation switches/property.

More details in [Maven's help plugin page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/all-profiles-mojo.html)

Answer (score 10):

Do you always want to see the active profile in your build log? Then you could add the following plugin config to the <build> section.

In this example I added the plugin to the phase 'compile'. It could easily be added to a different phase.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>show-profiles</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>active-profiles</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 5):

this works in maven 3.x 
`mvn help:active-profiles`

Answer (score -3):

```
mvn help:effective-profiles
```

Works to list the active profiles

Comment: [ERROR] Could not find goal 'effective-profiles' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2 among available goals expressions, active-profiles, effective-settings, system, effective-pom, help, all-profiles, describe, evaluate -> [Help 1]